# Upgrading Git for Windows to version 2 causes Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git

I am trying to upgrade Git for Windows as the old version has noted security issues. Also other software upgrades are requiring it.  However, when I do so, I always get `Permission denied (publickey)`.  This happens even after I create a new key.

Since this is Windows, I am using the very old OpenSSH for Windows.  To upgrade, I would have to convert to another package and would prefer to avoid simultaneous complicating changes.

Since Git works normally under the current version, I believed the keys, the repositories and the environment were okay.  The problem seemed isolated to the upgrade.

Note: I have resolved this problem though the resolution was difficult to find.  I am posting the issue here so that I can post the solution as well.

Command sequence, old version:

```
git push staging patches:master
Everything up-to-date

where git
D:\BitNami\rubystack-2.0.0-11\git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

git version
git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0
```

Command sequence, new version:

```
git push staging patches:master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

where git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

git version
git version 2.6.4.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the Git for Windows [FAQ's](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ).

> Some DSA keys are not considered secure anymore by OpenSSH 7. Adding
>   "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss" to ~/.ssh/config helps.

Note that this does result in a concern as to whether the keys are sufficiently secure.  If that is a problem, you might need to find a [replacement](http://www.openssh.com/windows.html) for OpenSSH for Windows.  I don't know if those replacements only support SSH or whether they would support another package like Git...

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the ssh key to your user agent again.

#### Open git bash and run this:

```
// start the ssh-agent in the background
eval $(ssh-agent -s)

// Now re-add your certificates and try to connect
ssh-add
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I posted the answer.  I didn't post interim, failed solutions.  This was one of those.  Thanks.  Also, please avoid unnecessary edits such as those your provided.  Thank you.